# Free Google Translate API usage

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api) translation API but I can't figure out how to include it in my project. I downloaded the package and tried to use `requireJS` to load it but using the function the author provides in the "Usage" section gives me errors.
What's the correct way to use it?

Errors:

> Error: Module name "querystring" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

`querystring` being the first line of index.js in the API package

> SyntaxError: Identifier 'translate' has already been declared

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @ArjanFrans errors added to the post

Comment: I think that is unofficial Google Translate API. Here you can find the official Google API for translation: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Comment: @Osoter Of course that's not official but the original API it's not for private (i.e. it's not free).

Comment: You can use the Translitered API but it's deprecated as mentioned https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started

In the last case you can use the Google Translate Tool. Here can you find a snippet code. http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/NQ4uE/

Comment: @Osoter I need the features of that API (auto language detection in particular), so answer the original question if you can thanks.

Comment: I believe the code holder should be the one you should seek assistance with